# SubMenu clicking issue in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, submenu, mousehover

I have to click a submenu which is dynamic : (hover on)Menu ->Submenu appears

My selenium code is

```
element1 =wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("parent_26")));
builder1.moveToElement(element1).clickAndHold(element1).build().perform();
element2=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver1.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='parentGroup_26']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[12]/div/a"))));
builder1.moveToElement(element1).clickAndHold(element1).moveToElement(element2).click(element2).build().perform();
```

During execution, **element1** gets clicked and submenu blinks.
After executing this there is no error but the **element2**(i.e submenu ) is not getting clicked.

I have tried using **moveToOffset()** also but did not work.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting into trouble because of [**clickAndHold**](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#clickAndHold--) method; as the name suggests and as per the use, it clicks (without releasing) at the current mouse location. Hence, the next method in line (as per your code), i.e., `moveToElement(element2)` is not working.

Please try the below code and see if that works for you :

**For hovering over element1 and then clicking on element2 in one-go:-**

```
WebElement element1;
element1 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("parent_26")));

WebElement element2;    
element2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='parentGroup_26']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[12]/div/a"));

//Hovering over element1 and then moving to element2 and clicking it; all in one-go
builder1.moveToElement(element1).moveToElement(element2).click(element2).build().perform();
```

**OR**

**For hovering over element1 first and then clicking on the element2 after that:-**

```
WebElement element1;
element1 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("parent_26")));

//Hovering over element1
builder1.moveToElement(element1).build().perform();

WebElement element2;
element2 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='parentGroup_26']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[12]/div/a"))));

//Moving to element2 and clicking it.
builder1.moveToElement(element2).click().build().perform();
```

And, just a suggestion. Please try using [**relative xpaths instead of absolute one**](http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/choosing-effective-xpath/). It's much more efficient.

Comment: I tried doing this but what happened was submenu disppeared before clicking and the link under the submenu got clicked...Please help me out

Comment: Is this a public site, you are automating ? If it is, please give the URL; it will be easier to sort out your problem then. 
If not, please do let me know, if **clicking (not hovering)** on the `element1` brings up the dropdown containing `element2 too`..

Comment: I used click instead of ClickAndHold and tried but no luck. Can it be application problem? Any suggestions please. Also, the one am working on is not a public site. Before clicking element1 itself, dropdown containing element2 is appearing (bcos of hovering).